# Установка мадженто

Tags: php

Добрый день. первый раз пробовал установить мадженто на локальный хост. При установке все ошибки устранил и вроде все поставилось. Но вид админки и самого сайта имеется не тот, который должен быть. Картинки не грузятся и стили не те. Ссылки на скрины прилагаю.
[первый скрин](http://joxi.ru/a2XZP1OFyPPWYr)

[второй скрин](http://joxi.ru/4AkoxVGCMZZnZA)

Comment: Композер обновили? Сгенерировать статику

Comment: Naumov, нет только поставил. я не очень знаю как это делается еще...с мадженто не работал. По просмотренным видосам - там сразу было норм. сейчас попробую

Comment: Права доступа дали?
777 на папки magento/var, magento/app/etc, magento/media. например, chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/media

Comment: Rapax, а это как сделать? я менял только на хосте.